# How to Extract a struct from byte array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

I have a struct in C in my Embedded MCU, it's something like this

```
struct setting_registers
{
uint16_t CNT;
char name[32];
float calibrate[4][16];
int some_setting;
...
about 1000 elements!
};
```

I have transferred the Struct into my C# app with serial port, now I have a byte array that contains my Struct from the MCU, something like this

```
int bytes = serialPort.BytesToRead;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
```

Now I want to have a similar Struct or class in C# and extract every info from this received byte array,
I wanted to do a brute force casting like this,

```
int CNT = 0;
CNT = buffer[0]*256 + buffer[1] ;
```

But it will take ages! and if I change the struct in my MCU then I should do all sort of things by hand in C# code too! I wanted to know if there is a more clever way of doing it?

I have done the Struct serialization in the C inside the MCU like this

```
uint8_t objectPointer = (uint8_t)setting_registers; 
//Send Object 
for(uint16_t i=0;i<size_of_obj;i++)
{ 
     uart0_putChar(objectPointer[i]); 
}
```

I mean I can cast the whole struct to a pointer and send it serialy.
So if I just copy and past my big struct with 1000 elemnts to C# is there a way to do something like a for loop to copy the elemnts in the recived buffer into the Struct?

Comment: No, that SerialPort.Read() takes ages, that data conversion certainly does not.  Micro-optimizing it is very pointless.  But don't write it yourself, use BitConverter.ToInt16().  If it is really big-endian then keep what you have.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.

In the C I have done something like this

    static uint8_t *objectPointer = (uint8_t*)setting_registers;
    //Send Object
    for(uint16_t i=0;i<size_of_obj;i++)
    {
     uart0_putChar(objectPointer[i]);
    }
 
I mean I can cast the whole struct to a pointer and send it serialy.

So if I just copy and past my big struct with 1000 elemnts to C# is there a way to do something like a for loop to copy the elemnts in the recived buffer into the Struct?